# How to save mutual authentication HTTPS SSL/TLS Session Handshake from Nginx server

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, session

I have setup an Nginx installation in my server. I've set a restriction access to a resource only by client certification authentication. (Referring to RFC6101).

Now when a user get access with his certificate, his client performs a "TLS handshake" exchanging some messages. These messages can be used to prove the access of that specific user.

It seems (and **this is the problem**) Nginx doesn't permit to recover or to save these informations, losing them forever.

**I want** to save (as a text file, or in a DB, or everything else) all the handshake messages exchanged between client and server. The goal is to prove that user performed a successful access. More specifically I need to save the *Certificate Verify* and all the relative messages used to produce it. (Referring to [RFC6101#CertificateVerify](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6101#page-34))